# Jekyll truncate number of blog posts conditional on excluding some

Tags: arrays, jekyll, limit, blogs, liquid

On my Jekyll website, I have an overview page on which I list my last 10 blog posts.

However, I also assign a tag `exclude` to some of my blog posts and those I don't want to show. This works, but then I don't get the last 10 blog posts, but 10 minus the number of `exclude` blog posts.

Here is how that looks like:

```
---
layout: page
title: "Last posts"
permalink: /last/
---

### Last posts

{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
    {% unless post.category == "exclude"%}
      * {{ post.date | date_to_string }} &raquo; [ {{ post.title }} ]({{ post.url }})
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I always show the last 10 non-`exclude` blog posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the last 10 non-exclude blog posts:

1. Create an array with posts that doesn't contain the `exclude` tag.

   ```
   {% assign nonexcludeposts = ''|split:''%}
   {% for post in site.posts %}
       {% unless post.category == "exclude"%}
       {% assign nonexcludeposts = nonexcludeposts|push:post%}
       {% endunless %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Display 10 most recent posts

   ```
   <ul>
   {% for post in nonexcludeposts limit:10 %}
         <li>
         <a href="{{post.url|absolute_url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
         </li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: It extracts the posts and the right number of them, but this list does not render properly for me. Maybe I'm including this wrong. On the page it then displays: * 08 Aug 2017 &raquo; [ My great post ](/2017/08/08/my-great-post/)
* 28 Jul 2017 &raquo; [ Another good post ](/2017/07/28/another-good-poost/) ... [the other posts] ...

Comment: I've used the original code in that part because it wasn't related to the question, to generate hyperlinks for each post use replace it with `<a href="{{post.url|absolute_url}}">{{post.title}}</a>`.